# Android/OpenGL ES2: How do I set fragment shader value using C;

Tags: android, opengl-es

This should be easy So I am using the following to create a fragment shader.

```
 GLbyte fShaderStr[] = "precision mediump float;"
    "void main()                                \n"
    "{                                          \n"
    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n"
    "}                                          \n";
```

I then render a circle (collection of lines) the circle comes our red. If I change the code to...

```
GLbyte fShaderStr[] = "precision mediump float;"
    "void main()                                \n"
    "{                                          \n"
    "  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); \n"
    "}                                          \n";
```

The circle is now purple. My question is how do I control this dynamically? So for example when I receive an input I toggle the two colors?

I tried...

```
GLbyte vShaderStr[] = "attribute vec4 vPosition;   \n"
            "attribute vec4 inColor;   \n"
    "uniform mat4 Projection;   \n"
    "varying vec4 fragColor;   \n"
    "void main()                 \n"
    "{                           \n"
    "   gl_Position = Projection * vPosition; \n"
    "   fragColor = inColor; \n"
    "}                           \n";

GLbyte fShaderStr[] = "precision mediump float;"
    "varying vec4 fragColor;                   \n"
    "void main()                                \n"
    "{                                          \n"
    "  gl_FragColor = fragColor; \n"
    "}\n";


void initColor(){
    LOGD("Initing Color");
    GLfloat vVertices[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices);
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as the circle is now black.

Comment: You need uniforms: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_%28GLSL%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

before your call to **glVertexAttribPointer**.

Basically any attribute is disabled by default, so you may have to enable it first. See [this](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml).

**Edit**

msell comment made me realize that you probably want the circle to be of single color, in that case yes, you need uniforms. Attributes are a property of vertices, so you would use attributes when you want to paint different vertices with different colors. Also, in that case you would need to specify a color for each vertex, so your **vVertices** array would need to have 4 floats for each vertex you are going to draw.

**How to do it**

The function you need is in the family of [glUniform](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) and most likely is **glUniform4f** because you want to set a color that is represented by 4 floats. You should declare your color in the **fragment shader** as a uniform:

```
uniform vec4 inColor;
```

Then in your application code you would do:

```
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "inColor");
glUniform4f(location, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

**Little explanation**

Usually it doesn't make sense to derive the value of a **varying** solely from **uniforms** in the vertex shader; the reason is that **uniforms** are *uniform* across all possible vertices shaded during the current draw call. The **varyings** are varying in the sense that the vertex shader computes their value for each vertex of a triangle, and then the interpolation units on the graphic card constructs all the intermediate values corresponding to the generated fragments. Since a **uniform** value is the same for each vertex, each fragment would get the same value. That is, if you use a **uniform** to decide in the vertex shader that all vertices are purple, the interpolator will generate all the shades of purple between purple and purple, that is, purple.

Instead, if you specify colors as **attributes** it is necessary to generate all intermediate shades across the triangle, so it makes sense to assign the **attribute** to the varying.

**Reference**

- [glUniform](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml)

**Square**

You need 6 positions:

```
-1.0, -1.0, 0.0
+1.0, -1.0, 0.0
-1.0, +1.0, 0.0
-1.0, +1.0, 0.0
+1.0, -1.0, 0.0
+1.0, +1.0, 0.0
```

And two colors, spread over two triangles:

```
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Red
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Red
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Red
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Green
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Green
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 // Green
```

And then use a call like:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Is there an example on how to change a uniform? Does the value in the shade renderer also change to a uniform?

Comment: You already have a **uniform** in your program, it's the **mat4 Projection**. In addition to have **uniforms** in the vertex shader, you can also have them in the fragment shader. In your code you should have a call to **glUniformMatrix4fv**, because, I repeat, you are already using **uniforms** for the projection matrix. You need to do something similar for the **uniform inColor**, and the API you need is **glUniform4f**. Check the code in my answer.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind (you have been very helpful so far). If I change it over to a square made from a triangle strip and I set up a vec 4 with 8 floats (4 for each of the two triangles in the strip) I was hoping to see two different color triangles but instead I get what looks like a gradient from one color to the other. How would I make each triangle have a different color.

Comment: Are you using **uniforms** or **attributes**? To paint a multicolored object with a single draw call you most likely need **attributes**. Also, a square made from triangle strip is such that the two triangles share two vertices. They not only share the position of the vertices, but also any other **attribute**, including color. If I where you I would sue **GL_TRIANGLES** instead of **GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP** and specify 6 vertices in total, three with one color, and the other three with another one. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I finally got it working after a bunch of rereading about the differences between uniform vary and attribute. Working as expected now, of course not I need to learn texturing :-)

Comment: You are welcome :-) If you are interested in a simple multitexturing setup you can have a look at http://www.damix.it/labgl and just play with the shader (    try to put this code inside main: **vec3 a = texture2D(uSamplerA, vTexCoords).rgb;
  vec3 b = texture2D(uSamplerB, vTexCoords).rgb;
  gl_FragColor = vec4((a + b) / 2.0, 1.0);**    ), or look at the Javascript WebGL code (it is similar to OpenGL ES, but not the same). Also, a good resource for learning modern OpenGL is http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/.